# Use an installer to add .NET User Control to Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, installaware

I am creating a .NET user control that I will be distributing using a commercial Installer. How do I automatically add the user control to the Visual Studio Toolbox when my installer runs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Toolbox controls installer. Check this tutorial from MSDN : Tutorial: [Installing Controls By Using the Toolbox Controls Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286995%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> This tutorial explains how to use the
>   Toolbox Controls Installer (TCI). When
>   you have finished this tutorial, you
>   will have created full-featured
>   installers for both Windows Forms
>   controls and Web Forms controls that
>   you can install into the Visual Studio
>   Toolbox by using the Toolbox Controls
>   Installer (TCI).

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Toolbox Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/vstudiotoolbox) is one approach to check into, also [this blog post](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2006/01/29/installing-components-in-the-visual-studio-toolbox/) has reference to how to go about it like the big component players, using the [visual studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx), they also have some other options with sample code on that blog

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this tutorial article discussing all the methods I know about so far:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

The Toolbox Controls Installer (TCI) seems to be most convenient one.

The Visual Studio Toolbox Manager on CodePlex is fine, but quite slow. I wrote a similar tool (available for download from the article) which deals with VS2012.

Finally, I wrote some notes about updating and uninstalling the controls.